# How can you remove/add specific grid line in excel diagram?

Tags: excel, line, axis

So, I want to keep only 1 red axis line. By default it shows or removes both of them, shows 1 line for each "row".
Don't know how to change my excel to english, sorry.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

You need to use some tricks for this. Use an XY Scatter chart and plot the two lines as two series, one for the horizontal line, one for the vertical line.

Then format the axes to the desired maximum and remove all the grid lines.

[image]

If you want only specific numbers to show on the axes, remove the axis labels altogether and use data labels for data points instead.

[image]